# Expand-Collapse toggle hiding all li items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an expand/collapse button on my site to manipulate list items. However, when I initiate the collapse all, everything disappears, even the first item. From there my only option is to expand all so I can see anything.

JS:

```
function prepareList() {
  $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)').click( function(event) {
      if (this == event.target) {
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
        $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
      }
      return false;
    })
    .addClass('collapsed').children('ul').hide();

        //Create the toggle 
        var toggle = false;
      $('#listToggle').unbind('click').click(function(){
        if(toggle == false){
          $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
          $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
          $('#listToggle').text("Collapse All");
          toggle = true;
        }else{
          $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
          $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
          $('#listToggle').text("Expand All");
          toggle = false;          
        }
      });

  $('#expList').find('li').click( function(event) {
    siteUrl =  $(this).attr('value');
      if(this.id != 'myList'){
                  RefreshSiteLists(siteUrl);
              } else{
                  RefreshSiteLists(siteUrl);
              }
              return false;
    });
}
```

HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/9HxGp/

Basically when I collapse, everything disappears. This only happens when I add a `<span>` around my text.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the fiddle doesn't work. Can you please specify what this should do? Should this create expandable tree list?

Comment: In the picture (hopefully not too small) when you collapse all, all sub level items should collapse and "Sharepoint Demo Website" should remain open and the image changes to a plus sign (css). This works fine until, I wrap <span> in my list item text. What happens then is that everything disappears when I select collapse even the top level site. So there's nothing for me to expand at that point. I don't know why adding a span tag is causing this but I assume it has to do with the jquery selector

Comment: ok, fixed the jsfiddle to working-broken state, by adding jquery and executing `prepareList()` - http://jsfiddle.net/9HxGp/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wasn't able to understand the issue (sorry, it's late) I took some liberties and made it so that it's a collapsable tree view, where elements of 2nd level can be collapsed, and `#listToggle` expands all (if there are any collapsed), which is accessible here: http://jsfiddle.net/daMZp/1/. I've also replaced the collapsed class a little to do what I see it does in the screenshot.

Then I looked at it again, and yes, now I see what's happening. I've fixed it for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/9HxGp/6/ (at  least, if you can call it fixed - hey, the top level stays visible, but still the behavior of such tree isn't right).

Now, to understand what's happening, let's take a look at list without any spans: http://jsfiddle.net/AD4rX/1/. Adding console logs gives us interesting results (http://jsfiddle.net/9HxGp/9/ and http://jsfiddle.net/AD4rX/2/) - basically, doing `$('.collapsed').children()` targets `ul`'s and `span`'s of the given `li` - thus, the label will disappear when trying to collapse. Of course this will behave differently, when there are only text nodes (and `ul`) within `li`, as jquery will then target only `ul`, leaving the text labels visible. With that knowledge, we can fall back to the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/9HxGp/10/, where we target all `:not(span)` children of the given `li`.

Sorry, for this going back and forth, but at least it's the answer to "why?".

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be something to do with your child selectors. I fixed up the jsfiddle so it ran - see my comments above. All that was needed was a tweak to the selectors for the button's click handler, ending up with this:

```
$('#listToggle').unbind('click').click(function(){
    if(toggle == false){
      $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
      $('.collapsed').children().show('medium').children().show(); //needed to add a second level to make everything show here for some reason
      $('#listToggle').text("Collapse All");
      toggle = true;
    }else{
      $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
      $('.collapsed').find('li').hide('medium'); //specifically hides li children
      $('#listToggle').text("Expand All");
      toggle = false;          
    }
  });
```

Note: I'm not sure if the lower-level menu items are intended to collapse or not?

http://jsfiddle.net/9HxGp/4/

Comment: Hmm I guess it would probably make sense that the child items also collapse.

Comment: I tried your fiddle but you'll notice that after you collapse all, you can't click on the plus icon to expand anymore.

Comment: Ah! There are some broken links - I assume you're on an intranet? It's a bit tough for me to test, because I can't see those buttons :)

Comment: Yea it's an intranet but I tried the changes on my site and it behaved the same way.